# Can I use POSIX file operations on android?

Tags: android, file, posix

I have part of the code for injecting touch event on android. But there is a Error:(54, 5) error: use of undeclared identifier 'write', I'm using ndk r15 and **ANDROID_API** is 21.I want to know is it possible to use posix file operations on android?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <linux/uinput.h>

/* Globals */
static int uinp_fd = -1;
struct uinput_user_dev uinp; // uInput device structure
struct input_event event; // Input device structure
/* Setup the uinput device */
int setup_uinput_device()
{
    // Temporary variable
    int i=0;

// Open the input device
uinp_fd = open("/dev/uinput", O_WRONLY | O_NDELAY);
if (uinp_fd == 0)
{
    printf("Unable to open /dev/uinput/n");
    return -1;
}

memset(&uinp,0,sizeof(uinp)); // Intialize the uInput device to NULL
strncpy(uinp.name, "PolyVision Touch Screen", UINPUT_MAX_NAME_SIZE);
uinp.id.version = 4;
uinp.id.bustype = BUS_USB;

// Setup the uinput device
ioctl(uinp_fd, UI_SET_EVBIT, EV_KEY);
ioctl(uinp_fd, UI_SET_EVBIT, EV_REL);
ioctl(uinp_fd, UI_SET_RELBIT, REL_X);
ioctl(uinp_fd, UI_SET_RELBIT, REL_Y);
for (i=0; i < 256; i++) {
    ioctl(uinp_fd, UI_SET_KEYBIT, i);
}

ioctl(uinp_fd, UI_SET_KEYBIT, BTN_MOUSE);
ioctl(uinp_fd, UI_SET_KEYBIT, BTN_TOUCH);
ioctl(uinp_fd, UI_SET_KEYBIT, BTN_MOUSE);
ioctl(uinp_fd, UI_SET_KEYBIT, BTN_LEFT);
ioctl(uinp_fd, UI_SET_KEYBIT, BTN_MIDDLE);
ioctl(uinp_fd, UI_SET_KEYBIT, BTN_RIGHT);
ioctl(uinp_fd, UI_SET_KEYBIT, BTN_FORWARD);
ioctl(uinp_fd, UI_SET_KEYBIT, BTN_BACK);

/* Create input device into input sub-system */
write(uinp_fd, &uinp, sizeof(uinp));
if (ioctl(uinp_fd, UI_DEV_CREATE))
{
    printf("Unable to create UINPUT device.");
    return -1;
}
return 1;
```

}

Comment: Have solved it, The POSIX file operrations are defined in unistd.h file.